# How do I use Thor actions without requiring a Thor CLI app?

Tags: ruby, thor

There are some great helper methods from Thor::Actions (http://textmate.rubyforge.org/thor/Thor/Actions.html) that I want access to but I cannot seem to use them without employing a Thor CLI app.

I've tried simply:

```
require "rubygems"
require "thor"

Thor::Actions.create_file "foo.txt", "contents"
```

Which throws:

`run.rb:4:in '<main>': undefined method 'create_file' for Thor::Actions:Module (NoMethodError)`

I realize I might be missing something really simple here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Thor intends for your classes to subclass the Thor class. The Thor class then includes and extends modules allowing their methods to be class methods. If you look at the source, for example `Actions.rb`, you will see what I mean:

```
# thor/lib/thor/actions.rb

class Thor
  module Actions

    # this is the interesting part and answers your question
    def self.included(base) #:nodoc:
      base.extend ClassMethods
    end

    module ClassMethods
```

This is a common Ruby idiom that uses a mixin to define class methods (as opposed to instance methods) on its inclusor.

As an example,

```
[2] pry(main)> class Klass
[2] pry(main)*   module Mod  
[2] pry(main)*     def self.included(base)    
[2] pry(main)*       base.extend ClassMethods      
[2] pry(main)*     end  
[2] pry(main)*     module ClassMethods    
[2] pry(main)*       def act_as_class_method      
[2] pry(main)*         puts "Im a class method now!!!"        
[2] pry(main)*       end  
[2] pry(main)*     end  
[2] pry(main)*   end  
[2] pry(main)* end  
=> nil
```

Now calling

```
Klass::Mod.act_as_class_method
```

results in the same error you had

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `act_as_class_method' for Klass::Mod:Module
from (pry):26:in `__pry__'
```

But if you subclass `Klass` and `include Klass::Mod` the `included` call back `extends` the `ClassMethod` module, letting you use the methods defined in `ClassMethods` as class methods

```
[4] pry(main)> class Example < Klass
[4] pry(main)*   include Klass::Mod

[4] pry(main)*   self.act_as_class_method
[4] pry(main)* end  

=> Im a class method now!!!
=> nil
```

This took me a while to figure out at first, so don't feel bad and no, its not that simple or obvious.

Answer (score 5):

To use `Thor::Actions` without inheriting from `Thor`:

```
class Builder # or whatever
  # To get your hands on the `from_superclass` method
  include Thor::Base

  # What we're interested in…
  include Thor::Actions
  source_root "/path/to/where/things/come/out"

  def initialize(*)
    # whatever you might want to do
    @destination_stack = [self.class.source_root]
  end
end
```

Hope someone else finds this useful. Tried and tested with Thor v0.18.1; as this is internal API stuff it's likely to break at some point in the future.

You can then use the helper methods in your `Builder` class like so:

```
class Builder
  def build
    in_root { 'do things' }
    create_file 'etc'
  end
end
```

**Edit:** If you want to control where you create files and folders you need to set `destination_root` like so:

```
class Builder
  include Thor::Base
  include Thor::Actions
  source_root Dir.pwd

  def initialize(root)
    self.destination_root = File.expand_path(root)
  end

  def build
    directory 'templates', 'target'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Thor myself, but I don't think it's set up to work that independently.

Try creating a Thor task internally, and then starting it.

Here's an example I've tried out, and placed in a file called `thor_createfile.rb` (I've put in some additional things I'll explain after the code that might be enlightening for you):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'    
require 'thor'

class MyThorTasks < Thor
  include Thor::Actions

  default_task :createInflexibleFile

  desc "createFile <fname> <content>", "Creates a file with some content"
  def createFile(fname, content)
    create_file fname, content
  end

  INFLEXIBLE_FILENAME = "the_filename.txt"
  INFLEXIBLE_CONTENT = "Greetings, Earthlings!"

  desc "createInflexibleFile", "Creates a file called '#{INFLEXIBLE_FILENAME}' containing '#{INFLEXIBLE_CONTENT}'"
  def createInflexibleFile
    puts "Creating a file called '#{INFLEXIBLE_FILENAME}' containing '#{INFLEXIBLE_CONTENT}'"
    create_file INFLEXIBLE_FILENAME, INFLEXIBLE_CONTENT
  end
end

MyThorTasks.start
```

You can see it defines a class that extends `Thor`, and then calls the `start` method on it.

Now you should be able to call it simply like this:

```
./thor_createfile.rb
```

and it will use the task designated as `default_task`.

But if you need to take some command-line parameters, you can explicitly call tasks by name.  So to call the other task, for example:

```
./thor_createfile.rb createFile fancy_file_name.txt "Text to go inside the file"
```

Note I've told it to `include Thor::Actions` so all the items you were interested in (like `create_file`) are available.

Now you can add other tasks inside it (make sure to add the `desc` for each one or it will probably complain) and use those too, as needed.

To have it tell you about all of the tasks defined inside it, you can call it this way:

```
./thor_createfile.rb -?
```

Comment: Just a small stylistic point… you'll tend to find methods use snake case in most Ruby code. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case